# AtrributeError: type object 'Player' has no attribute 'image_dict'

Tags: python, pygame

Been trying to get a dictionary working for some sprites.

```
class Player(Digimon):
def __init__(self):
    super(Player, self).__init__(0,2,0,0,0,0) # age, weight, str, def, speed, intelligence
    self.image_dict = {(0,2,0,0,0,0): itertools.cycle([pygame.image.load("images/egg_sprite_1.png"),
                                                   pygame.image.load("images/egg_sprite_2.png"), 
                                                   pygame.image.load("images/egg_sprite_3.png")]), 
                   (2,4,0,0,2,5): itertools.cycle([pygame.image.load("images/leaf_1.png"), 
                                                    pygame.image.load("images/leaf_2.png"), 
                                                    pygame.image.load("images/leaf_3.png"),
                                                    pygame.image.load("images/leaf_4.png")])}
```

and then in the main loop

```
Player.images = Player.image_dict[(Player.age, Player.weight, Player.strength, Player.defence, Player.speed, Player.intelligence)] 

Player.image = next(Player.images)
```

I get the error stated in the title. I've looked at similar questions, but they don't seem to help. As far as I can see, it should work. Player.image_dict is created in the Player(digimon) subclass, so I don't know how there is no attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you actually need to create an instance of the `Player` class as follows:

`player = Player()`

Then you can call:

```
player.images = player.image_dict[(player.age, player.weight, player.strength, player.defence, player.speed, player.intelligence)] 

player.image = next(player.images)
```

Note these are `player` the object, not `Player` the class

Comment: Aw, man. Such a silly mistake. Thanks loads!

One question: Why player, and not Player? Is it to stop confusion, or something that may cause a problem when it runs?

Comment: No problem. Happy pygaming!

Comment: @user3384265, If that solved your problem then can you accept the answer to resolve the question. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

`Player.image_dict`

this way you can only access ststic members of class `Player`. If you dont want to do that you need to create a object of the class player. like this

```
Player player = Player(<arguments>)
player.image_dict(...)
```